# Error with pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays during groupby merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. They look like this:

```
df_a
     Framecount                                        probability
0           0.0  [0.00019486549333333332, 4.883635666666667e-06...
1           1.0  [0.00104359155, 3.9232405e-05, 0.0015722045000...
2           2.0  [0.00048501002666666667, 1.668179e-05, 0.00052...
3           3.0  [4.994969500000001e-05, 4.0931635e-07, 0.00011...
4           4.0  [0.0004808829, 5.389742e-05, 0.002522127933333...
..          ...                                                ...
906       906.0  [1.677140566666667e-05, 1.1745095666666665e-06...
907       907.0  [1.5164155000000002e-05, 7.66629575e-07, 0.000...
908       908.0  [8.1334184e-05, 0.00012675669636333335, 0.0028...
909       909.0  [0.00014893802999999998, 1.0407592500000001e-0...
910       910.0  [4.178489e-05, 2.17477925e-06, 0.02094931, 0.0...
```

And:

```
df_b
     start    stop
0     12.12   12.47
1     13.44   20.82
2     20.88   29.63
3     31.61   33.33
4     33.44   42.21
..      ...     ...
228  880.44  887.92
229  888.63  892.07
230  892.13  895.30
231  895.31  900.99
232  907.58  908.35
```

I want to merge `df_a.probability` onto `df_b` when `df_a.Framecount` is in between df_b.start and `df_b.stop`. The aggregation statistic for `df_a.probability` should be `mean`. `df_a.probability` is dtype np array.

I am trying to adapt my answer from this code:

```
df_text.idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_b['start'],df_b['stop'],closed='both')
df_a['Framecount'].apply(lambda x : df_b.iloc[df_b.idx.get_loc(x)]['probability'].mean())
```

but it breaks with the first line with this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-200-0c75f94bf6e2> in <module>
----> 1 df_textidx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_text['start'],df_text['stop'],closed='both')
      2 df_vid['Framecount'].apply(lambda x : df_text.iloc[df_text.idx.get_loc(x)]['probability'])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/interval.py in from_arrays(cls, left, right, closed, name, copy, dtype)
    314         with rewrite_exception("IntervalArray", cls.__name__):
    315             array = IntervalArray.from_arrays(
--> 316                 left, right, closed, copy=copy, dtype=dtype
    317             )
    318         return cls._simple_new(array, name=name)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/interval.py in from_arrays(cls, left, right, closed, copy, dtype)
    380 
    381         return cls._simple_new(
--> 382             left, right, closed, copy=copy, dtype=dtype, verify_integrity=True
    383         )
    384 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/interval.py in _simple_new(cls, left, right, closed, copy, dtype, verify_integrity)
    239         result._closed = closed
    240         if verify_integrity:
--> 241             result._validate()
    242         return result
    243 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/interval.py in _validate(self)
    486         if not (self.left[left_mask] <= self.right[left_mask]).all():
    487             msg = "left side of interval must be <= right side"
--> 488             raise ValueError(msg)
    489 
    490     # ---------

ValueError: left side of interval must be <= right side
```

Why is this happening? IIUC the left side is <= right side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- All left side values must be less than right side values, which isn't an issue with the test data provided.
- For [`pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html#pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays), the `left` and `right` parameter require a `1-d` array.

  - `.from_arrays(df_b['start'], df_b['stop'])` passes a `pandas.DataFrame`
  - [`df_b['start'].values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) will pass an `np.array`.
  - Either should work.
- Also see [pandas: Indexing with an IntervalIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#indexing-with-an-intervalindex)

```py
import pandas as pd

# setup the test dataframe
data = {'start': [12.12, 13.44, 20.88, 31.61, 33.44, 880.44, 888.63, 892.13, 895.31, 907.58], 'stop': [12.47, 20.82, 29.63, 33.33, 42.21, 887.92, 892.07, 895.3, 900.99, 908.35]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create the interval index by passing the column as np.array
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.start.values, df.stop.values, closed='both')

# display(idx)
IntervalIndex([[12.12, 12.47], [13.44, 20.82], [20.88, 29.63], [31.61, 33.33], [33.44, 42.21], [880.44, 887.92], [888.63, 892.07], [892.13, 895.3], [895.31, 900.99], [907.58, 908.35]],
              closed='both',
              dtype='interval[float64]')
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Turns out I had some 'start' values bigger than the 'stop' values, so once that was cleaned up this works